# Row wise by group sum with conditions

Tags: r

The aim is for an ID to be treated as a group and sum the rows of the distinct ID based on a set of conditions row wise.

The data is time dependent for any `item_ID`, we are interested to see if at the `check_date` of a given `item_ID`, do all `item_ID`s (including the row selected) of that `ID` group have `start_dates` less than the given `item_ID` AND the `fail_dates` are either greater than the `check_date` of the given `item_ID` OR `NA`. When these conditions are met, sum the `value` column whilst maintaining the `ID` grouping.

Using the example below and starting at row 1 then iterating down rows, sum the row `values` of an `ID`'s `item_ID`s when either:

1. `df$fail_date` == `NA` AND `df$check_date[1]` >= `start_date`, OR
2. `df$fail_date` > `df$check_date[1]` AND `df$check_date[1]` >= `start_date`

where `df$start_date[1]` is the first row of `check_date` which gets iterated down rows

Example data:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3),
                 start_date = c(44107, 44107, 44107, 44226, 44233, 44289, 44107, 44107, 44226, 44107, 44107, 44107, 44107, 44233, 44233, 44233, 44233),
                 check_date = c(44121, 44121, 44121, 44240, 44247, 44303, 44121, 44121, 44240, 44121, 44121, 44121, 44121, 44247, 44247, 44247, 44247),  
                 fail_date = c(NA, NA, 44114, NA, 44328, NA, 44207, 44196, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),  
                 value = c(30, 25, 60, 20, 30, 15, 50, 20, 15, 30, 25, 20, 30, 20, 50, 20, 15))
```

The desired output would be:

```
   ID   item_ID start_date check_date fail_date value conditional_sum
1   1  B874_20K      44107      44121        NA    30              55
2   1 BB849_21E      44107      44121        NA    25              55
3   1 BB842_21E      44107      44121     44114    60              55
4   1  B873_20K      44226      44240        NA    20             105
5   1  B875_21E      44233      44247     44328    30             105
6   1 BB848_20K      44289      44303        NA    15             120
7   2  BD49_21K      44107      44121     44207    50              70
8   2  BU44_20J      44107      44121     44196    20              70
9   2  DD93_21E      44226      44240        NA    15              15
10  3  B874_20K      44107      44121        NA    30             105
11  3 BB849_21E      44107      44121        NA    25             105
12  3  B873_20K      44107      44121        NA    20             105
13  3  B875_21E      44107      44121        NA    30             105
14  3  B873_20K      44233      44247        NA    20             210
15  3  BD49_21K      44233      44247        NA    50             210
16  3  BU44_20J      44233      44247        NA    20             210
17  3 BB848_20K      44233      44247        NA    15             210
```

I'm really not sure how to crack this, my usual toolkit of dplyr group_by and summarise doesn't fit the bill. Any direction is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand what "sum all rows of an ID against that row and calculate for the next row" means.  How do you sum a set of rows _against_ a particular row? What does calculate "for the next row" mean? Are you doing a `cumsum`?

Comment: Just made an edit as it wasn't clear - its meant to be logic that applies per row to determine which of the value column to sum, not a cumsum.

Comment: How are groups defined? It seems the first three rows are one group, the following two are a second group, but then it is unclear to me why they form groups.

Comment: I've only provided one group defined by ID == 1, I can add more dummy data to show the distinction

Comment: Can you explain why row 4 and row 5 of the expected output have the same value?

Comment: Shouldn't all `value`s be the same?  The `ID` is the same for all.

Comment: What do you do with a row that doesn't satisfy the date requirements?  Do you `fill` down?  Does that row's contribute to the `conditional_sum`? If so, for which rows?

Comment: @MichaelDewar item_ID is distinct within ID. Value is assigned to item_ID, not ID. If all these rows had the same values it would make this problem a lot easier for sure! 

The conditions are applied each time a row is processed but the parameters are changed by the check_date of that particular row. So for example even if a fail_date occurs on any given row within the group, so long as it occurs after a check_date of the row being processed the value is still summed.

Comment: For a given `item_ID`, which rows get summed to give you `conditional_sum`?  Is it: (a) All rows of `ID` which meet the condition, or (b) All above rows of `ID` which meet the condition, or (c) all above rows of `ID` ?  Here, "above rows" may or may not include the current row.  Please specify.

Comment: @Maël A) For row 4, it's check_date is greater than the value of rows 1-5 AND rows 1, 2 and 4 have NAs for fail_date, and less than the fail_date of 5. So we sum 1, 2, 4 and 5 to give a conditional_sum of 105. B) For row 5, we apply the same logic - it's check_date is greater than the value of rows 1-5, fail_date is NA for 1, 2 and 4, and the fail_date of 5 is greater than its check_date, giving a conditional_sum of 105.

Comment: @MichaelDewar (a) All rows of ID which meet the condition

Comment: @Gareth, then all of the rows should have the same `condtional_sum`, since they are all of the same `ID`.

Comment: @MichaelDewar, I've added some more dummy data which might clarify the use of the ID column. If the dates of each item_ID were the same then yes, the conditional_sum would be the same, but the item_ID dates are unique, so render different conditional_sums. When calculating, the check_date of B874_20K is different from the check_date of B873_20K, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, a concise solution with [**`runner`**](https://rdrr.io/cran/runner/f/README.md) in the **`tidyverse`**:

## Solution

```
library(tidyverse)
library(runner)


# ...
# Code to generate 'df'.
# ...


df %>%
  # Work within each 'ID' group.
  group_by(ID) %>%

  # Use 'runner' to go downwards from row to row.
  mutate(conditional_sum = runner(check_date, function(x) {
    # Use the check date for the latest row.
    cur_check_date <- last(x)
    
    # Sum only those 'value's whose rows meet the conditions.
    sum(value[
      cur_check_date >= start_date & (is.na(fail_date) | fail_date > cur_check_date)
    ])
  }))
```

## Result

Given a `df` like the one reproduced here

```
df <- structure(
  list(
    ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3),
    item_ID = c(
      "B874_20K", "BB849_21E", "BB842_21E", "B873_20K", "B875_21E", "BB848_20K",
      "BD49_21K", "BU44_20J", "DD93_21E", "B874_20K", "BB849_21E", "B873_20K",
      "B875_21E", "B873_20K", "BD49_21K", "BU44_20J", "BB848_20K"
    ),
    start_date = c(
      44107, 44107, 44107, 44226, 44233, 44289, 44107, 44107, 44226, 44107,
      44107, 44107, 44107, 44233, 44233, 44233, 44233
    ),
    check_date = c(
      44121, 44121, 44121, 44240, 44247, 44303, 44121, 44121, 44240, 44121,
      44121, 44121, 44121, 44247, 44247, 44247, 44247
    ),
    fail_date = c(
      NA, NA, 44114, NA, 44328, NA, 44207, 44196, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
      NA, NA
    ),
    value = c(
      30, 25, 60, 20, 30, 15, 50, 20, 15, 30, 25, 20, 30, 20, 50, 20, 15
    )
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, -17L),
  class = "data.frame"
)
```

this solution should yield the following result:

```
# A tibble: 17 x 7
# Groups:   ID [3]
      ID item_ID   start_date check_date fail_date value contidional_sum
   <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>           <dbl>
 1     1 B874_20K       44107      44121        NA    30              55
 2     1 BB849_21E      44107      44121        NA    25              55
 3     1 BB842_21E      44107      44121     44114    60              55
 4     1 B873_20K       44226      44240        NA    20             105
 5     1 B875_21E       44233      44247     44328    30             105
 6     1 BB848_20K      44289      44303        NA    15             120
 7     2 BD49_21K       44107      44121     44207    50              70
 8     2 BU44_20J       44107      44121     44196    20              70
 9     2 DD93_21E       44226      44240        NA    15              15
10     3 B874_20K       44107      44121        NA    30             105
11     3 BB849_21E      44107      44121        NA    25             105
12     3 B873_20K       44107      44121        NA    20             105
13     3 B875_21E       44107      44121        NA    30             105
14     3 B873_20K       44233      44247        NA    20             210
15     3 BD49_21K       44233      44247        NA    50             210
16     3 BU44_20J       44233      44247        NA    20             210
17     3 BB848_20K      44233      44247        NA    15             210
```

---

## Benchmarking

It appears this approach is roughly 7 times faster than the [existing solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71053624) by [@MichaelDewar](https://stackoverflow.com/u/12744323)

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
  michael = {
    df_no_na <- df %>% replace_na(list(fail_date = max(df$check_date) + 1))
    
    conditional_sum_by_ID_and_check_date <- function(this_ID, this_check_date){
      df_no_na %>% 
        filter(ID == this_ID,
               fail_date > this_check_date,
               start_date <= this_check_date) %>% 
        summarize(conditional_sum = sum(value)) %>% 
        pull()
    }
    
    df %>% 
      distinct(ID, check_date) %>% 
      mutate(conditional_sum = map2_dbl(ID, check_date, conditional_sum_by_ID_and_check_date)) %>% 
      right_join(df, by = c("ID", "check_date"))
  },
  greg = {
    df %>%
      group_by(ID) %>%
      mutate(conditional_sum = runner(check_date, function(x) {
        cur_check_date <- last(x)
        sum(value[
          cur_check_date >= start_date & (is.na(fail_date) | fail_date > cur_check_date)
        ])
      }))
  }
)
```

as seen in the benchmarks for [`times = 100`](https://rdrr.io/cran/microbenchmark/man/microbenchmark.html#heading-1) evaluations apiece:

```
Unit: milliseconds
    expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
 michael 17.2701 18.37395 21.964745 18.77340 22.27915 147.3653   100
    greg  2.4107  2.70395  3.288304  2.92825  3.28625   8.9233   100
```

### Note

The relative performance might change for a dataset much larger than `df`, where I suspect the [`*_join()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate-joins.html)s will prove more costly.

Comment: This is a great answer!  I've never heard about `runner` before, but's exactly the kind of thing I often need.  As for speed, I tried your benchmark on a dataset with 1000 lines and the superiority of your method indeed becomes even greater.

Comment: @MichaelDewar Happy to hear it! And thanks for elaborating on the performance.  Did you happen to record the `mean` times?  I'm curious what they were...

Comment: I added the code I used for the benchmarking test data.  You answer was 215 times faster for 1000 lines of data.

Comment: @MichaelDewar Thank you for going to that effort!  I think it really enriches the solution.  :)

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3),
             start_date = c(44107, 44107, 44107, 44226, 44233, 44289, 44107, 44107, 44226, 44107, 44107, 44107, 44107, 44233, 44233, 44233, 44233),
             check_date = c(44121, 44121, 44121, 44240, 44247, 44303, 44121, 44121, 44240, 44121, 44121, 44121, 44121, 44247, 44247, 44247, 44247),  
             fail_date = c(NA, NA, 44114, NA, 44328, NA, 44207, 44196, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),  
             value = c(30, 25, 60, 20, 30, 15, 50, 20, 15, 30, 25, 20, 30, 20, 50, 20, 15)) %>% 
    mutate(item_ID = row_number())

df_no_na <- df %>% replace_na(list(fail_date = max(df$check_date) + 1))

conditional_sum_by_ID_and_check_date <- function(this_ID, this_check_date){
    df_no_na %>% 
        filter(ID == this_ID,
               fail_date > this_check_date,
               start_date <= this_check_date) %>% 
        summarize(conditional_sum = sum(value)) %>% 
        pull()
}

output_frame <- df %>% 
    distinct(ID, check_date) %>% 
    mutate(conditional_sum = map2_dbl(ID, check_date, conditional_sum_by_ID_and_check_date)) %>% 
    right_join(df, by = c("ID", "check_date"))
```

The basic idea is to map over the pairs of `ID`/`check_date`, compute your sum, and then join back to the original table.

You could avoid the `df_no_na` bit by complicating the `filter` expression.

### Benchmarking

I was curious about how much faster Greg's answer would be when the data size increased.  I created 1000 lines of test data using:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(runner)

num_id <- 100L
num_item <- 10L
num_days <- 100L

df <- tibble(ID = rep(1:num_id, each = num_item),
             item_ID = sample(1:num_item, num_id*num_item, replace = TRUE),
             start_date = sample(1:num_days, num_id*num_item, replace = TRUE),
             fail_date = sample(1:num_days, num_id*num_item, replace = TRUE),
             check_date = sample(1:num_days, num_id*num_item, replace = TRUE),
             value = sample(1:num_days, num_id*num_item, replace = TRUE))
```

Using the exact same benchmarking command from Greg's answer, you can see that his function is 215 times faster.

```
Unit: milliseconds
    expr       min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
 michael 3099.1283 3290.19973 3664.69723 3571.61724 3840.92476 5581.34401   100
    greg   13.2958   15.36794   17.29367   15.92426   18.22314   25.93559   100
```

Comment: How do I buy you a coffee? Clocking off so I've only run and the figures work for the full df, I'll need to go through since I've not seen a few of these functions before and comment back. Thank you so much for your time and making heads/tails of my explanations.